# Projective transformation between colinear points in 2D with 2x2 homography possible?

Tags: projection

Referring to: 2.5 The projective geometry of 1D by Richard Hartley and Andrew Zissermann.
Can I compute a projective transformation matrix 2x2 from two sets of 3 1D colinear points?

I want to find the projective transformation of 2 sets of 3 colinear points on a 2D sketch.

[pointset x and x'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89AI9.png)

solve for H using A:

\begin{equation*} 
\begin{bmatrix}
-x_1 & -1 &  u_1x_1 & u_1 \\
-x_2 & -1 &  u_2x_2 & u_2 \\
x_3 & -1 &  u3x_3 & u_3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} * \begin{bmatrix} h_{11} \\ h_{12} \\ h_{21} \\ h_{22}\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}